# Multiple button display on a message approval screen

Tags: buttons

We have a responsive website that uses Bootstrap. One of the pages is for approving a pending message for an email group. There are a lot of options available, currently displayed as a series of buttons. This first screenshot is the typical desktop view:

[image]

This second screenshot is the mobile view, with the More button pressed.

[image]

Like I said, that's a lot of buttons. How can I improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have at least two problems: **a UI issue** that causes high cognitive load and an **information architecture issue** with a mix of related and unrelated actions.

From what I can see, the UI has two basic elements: **message** and **user**. However, some actions are specific to the message while others are specific to the user, leading to confusion. Additionally, there are unclear actions like *"Skip"* and *"Cancel"* . Maybe they are OK, but without some context (like : what is this system for?), their purpose is unclear.

To resolve these issues, the first step is to clearly separate **what belongs to the user** and **what belongs to the message**. Then, you can improve the UI. For example, you can include user-related actions as icons next to the name.

Secondly, be more explicit with your actions and affordances. For example, clarify what *"Skip," "Cancel,"* and *"Delete"* mean. Additionally, consider if there is a reason for having both *"Reject"* and *"Delete."*

Finally, there may be a third element to the UI that I haven't mentioned yet because actions are unclear: **navigation.** If "Skip" and "Cancel" are navigational elements, then the UI has three components: *user, email, and navigation.* And in this case, you should group the actions according to each component