# Making a dropdown more apparent

Tags: buttons, interface

After the good advice here: [Multiple button display on a message approval screen](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/147371/multiple-button-display-on-a-message-approval-screen), I reformatted our pending email message approval page. It now looks like this:

[image]

I've made the sender's name a dropdown, as seen here:

[image]

But people are not seeing that the sender's name is a dropdown. How can I make it more apparent? I tried making it into a button, but that didn't look very good. Is there something else I can do to make it apparent that there's a dropdown there, with the functions related to that person?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I see an important problem that can interfere with the immediate interpretation by a user not used to this type of interface: the disparity in the sizes of the icons, where the smallest is precisely the perceptually conflicting one according to the statement of the question:

[image]

As a solution, I would try to unify criteria in the use of icons, both those that are framed in a button and those that are free. This doesn't mean they should all be the same size, but perceptually balanced.

Secondly, it would include a graphic that allows the user to interpret that the referenced element hides a menu:

[image]